# Как реализовать общение API друг между другом при помощи JWT(asp.net core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rest, jwt

Не могу придумать, как лаконично реализовать это.

```cs
public void AddCard(CardViewModel cardViewModel)
{
            var jwt = Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues.Empty;
            HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out jwt);
            _cardService.AddCard(cardViewModel, jwt);
}
```

Хочется избавиться от таких конструкций, то есть избавиться от передачи JWT таким образом в методы, которые кидают запросы к другим API. Может, можно сделать это через MiddleWare, идей пока нет.

Решил это(почти), при помощи промежуточного класса хранения JWT, который резолвят Middleware(он хватает JWT из HttpContext.DefaultRequestHeaders) и HttpClient, который коннектится к другим API, он запихивает в свой хидер запроса AuthorizationScheme с JWT из класса, где хранится сам JWT.
Класс коннекта к API:

```cs
 public ShellHttpClient(IConfiguration config, IJwtChest jwtChest)
        {
            _configuration = config;
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _jwtChest = jwtChest;         
        }

public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string action)
        {
            string a = _uri + action;
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _jwtChest.GetJwt());
            return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(a);
        }
```

Метод MiddleWare:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var jwt = Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues.Empty;
            context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out jwt);
            jwt = jwt.ToString().Split(' ').Last();
            _storage.SaveJwt(jwt);
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
```

Comment: почему нельзя обращаться сразу на вторую АПИ?

Comment: Потому что на них весит атрибут, и нужно чтобы к ним тоже прилетал валидный JWT.
Сделано для того, чтобы не было доступа у неавторизованных пользователей напрямую к API.

Comment: так приходит один и тот же токен на одну и на вторую апи, а между апишками можно использовать другую авторизацию, доступную только внутри

Comment: Если вдруг кому-то будет интересно, то я реализвовал так:
- middleware'ом ловлю из каждого реквеста jwt, потом кидаю в класс коннекшна к апи

Answer (score 1):

Вы с помощью JWT пытаетесь решать задачу, для которой он не подходит. JWT предназначен для передачи контекста исполнения приложения (например, контекста безопасности) между независимыми сервисами. Контекст исполнения - это свойства среды, в которой в данный момент существует запрос. Обычно это словарь "ключ-значение" содержащий, например, следующее:

- идентификатор арендатора ПО
- ИД пользователя
- права пользователя

Т.е. содержащаяся в JWT информация является аналогом переменных окружения в операционной системе.

К примеру, у вас есть следующая конфигурация:

- Приложение А: клиент (веб- или мобильный)
- Приложение Б: сервис 1 (веб-апи)
- Приложение В: сервис 2 (веб-апи)

Токен получает Приложение А и ходит с ним в приложение Б и В. Если у вас токен передаёт приложение Б при походе к приложению В, то это может свидетельствовать о неверных архитектурных решениях - информация, специфическая для конкретного запроса, не должна проникать в JWT.

Для связи двух независимых web-API сервисов обычно применяют либо прямые вызовы с помощью технологии обнаружения сервисов (service discovery) либо вводя промежуточное звено в виде брокера сообщений.